# Final position after CSS3 animation doesn't stick when using vh units and resizing browser window

Tags: css, animation, absolute

I have an image that is absolutely positioned using `vh` units. I want to animate this positioning use CSS. When doing so, however, the relative nature of `vh` units seems to be lost. To illustrate, look at the following two examples. In both of them, drag the bottom of your browser up and down to change its height.

### No animation

The positioning adjusts correctly in relation to the screen height.

http://codepen.io/maxedison/pen/jPOQPW

```css
#mountain {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 55vh;
  opacity: 1;
}
img {
  width: 180vh;
  margin-left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen1">
  <div id="mountain">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Red_Slate_Mountain_1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Animation**
The positioning does NOT adjust at all. It's like the `vh` unites have turned into static `px`, maintaining the same distance from the top of the window regardless of screen height.

http://codepen.io/maxedison/pen/QbWJbj

```css
#mountain {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: lincoln_page_load 2s ease forwards;
  animation: lincoln_page_load 2s ease forwards;
}
img {
  width: 180vh;
  margin-left: -50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes lincoln_page_load {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 55vh
  }
}
@keyframes lincoln_page_load {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 55vh
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="screen1">
  <div id="mountain">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Red_Slate_Mountain_1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to correct this? I know I can resort to JavaScript to make this work :)

Comment: @misterManSam Sorry, entered the wrong codepen link for the animation example. And I didn't realize Stackoverflow had implemented this code snippet feature. Very nice.

Comment: They are very neat, though they don't support Sass so you need to compile it first :)

Comment: @misterManSam They work fine for me with SASS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only a problem when the animation is paused with `forwards` and the animation is still active:

- Place the `top: 55vh` in `#mountain` so that when the animation ends it has this value and remove the `opacity: 0`
- Remove `forwards` so that the animation is completed
- Add the `opacity: 0` and `top: 100vh` to `from` in the keyframes so that these values are present when the page loads

This has the added benefit of showing the image if the browser does not support the `animation` property.

[Codepen Example with SASS](http://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/yNLGLv) (Auto-prefixer is turned on)

---

#### Using a transform for animation

[Here is another example](http://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/pJoqyL) using a transform — `translate` ([info link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Syntax)) — which seems to provide a slightly smoother animation.

---

### Working Example — vanilla CSS

```css
#mountain {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 55vh;
  -webkit-animation: lincoln_page_load 2s ease;
  animation: lincoln_page_load 2s ease;
}
img {
  width: 180vh;
  margin-left: -50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes lincoln_page_load {
  from {
    top: 100vh;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 55vh
  }
}
@keyframes lincoln_page_load {
  from {
    top: 100vh;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 55vh
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="screen1">
  <div id="mountain">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Red_Slate_Mountain_1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! In regards to your alternative example that uses translate, my actual page will have some content above #mountain, and that seems to make the translate functionality no longer the same since the removal of absolute positioning now matters: http://codepen.io/maxedison/pen/aObeJx. Do you have a suggestion on how to use translate in this kind of a situation?